# Django rest framework return validation error messages from endpoints

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Using

```
Django==3.0.8
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

I am trying to validate a GET endpoint which looks like this.

```
/users?role=Prospect&limit=10&offset=0
```

How can we validate this request in DRF using serializers.Serializer and get all the validation error messages when invalid and return in api response?

Serializer using for this request:

```
class UserIndexSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    offset = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    limit = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    role = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, default=None, max_length=255)
```

View function looks like:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def user_list(request):
    serializer = UserIndexSerializer(data=request.data) // trying to validate using this serializer
    print("query params", request.GET)
    print("request valid", serializer.is_valid())
    users = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserGetSerializer(users, many=True)
    return AppResponse.success("User list found.", serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `serializers.ValidationError` here.
To validate a field of name `xyz` you need to make a function named `validate_xyz` and write your validation code inside it.
For example, to validate the limit field of your serializer, we need to do:

```py
class UserIndexSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    offset = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    limit = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    role = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, default=None, max_length=255)
    
    def validate_limit(self, value):
        if limit > 5:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Limit cannot exceed 5.')
        return value
```

After defining these validator functions, you can check if the serializer is valid by doing

```py
serializer.is_valid()
```

django-rest-framework takes in the validation errors raised if any, and acts accordingly.

- **you need to return a value from the validator function.**